# Where to find Symfony2 clean skeleton?

Tags: php, symfony, skeleton-code

I need a clean skeleton, without default demos and configs, to understand all the configuration process, begin from zero, and bundle creation for Symfony 2.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but all it says are symfony-bootstrapper.git, that is no longer available, and Symfony2 standard download, that comes with the demo files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Download the [Standard Edition](http://symfony.com/download) with the Acme demo, inside that distribution is a file called `README.md` and at the bottom it has a section that describes how to remove the Acme stuff:

> ### Using this Edition as the Base of your Application
>
> Since the standard edition is fully-configured and comes with some
>   examples, you'll need to make a few changes before using it to build
>   your application.
>
> The distribution is configured with the following defaults:
>
> - Twig is the only configured template engine;
> - Doctrine ORM/DBAL is configured;
> - Swiftmailer is configured;
> - Annotations for everything are enabled.
>
> A default bundle, `AcmeDemoBundle`, shows you Symfony2 in action.
>   After playing with it, you can remove it by following these steps:
>
> - delete the `src/Acme` directory;
> - remove the routing entries referencing AcmeBundle in `app/config/routing_dev.yml`;
> - remove the AcmeBundle from the registered bundles in `app/AppKernel.php`;

You can also remove `web/bundles/acmedemo` as well since that is just assets which are installed using `php app/console assets:install web`.

Answer (score 1):

The demo files are just one bundle, and they actually help with understanding the configuration for Symfony2.  They also are only initialized in the development front controller and are easy to remove by deleting the bundle from your app Kernel and configs.

The Symfony2 framework is very challenging to learn because there are many different ways you can accomplish a given task.  Config files can be in different formats and in various locations.

Try using the Interactive Generator command line tool to create a bundle.  Here's a really good overview: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/page_creation.html

Good luck!